# LibreOffice shows me strange characters

Tags: libreoffice, xfce, debian-jessie

My LibreOffice shows strange symbols and characters. I am using Debian8 with XFCE environment. For better understand I have uploaded the screenshot.

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the font it's using.

Comment: I never had a problem like this. What do you mean with missing the font?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a definitive answer, but an answer is the only way to post an image.

It looks like the system font, or at least the one used by LibreOffice, has been changed, or is missing and another font has been substituted.  From the menu, click on Tools | Options | View and look at whether `Use system font for user interface` is checked:

[image: Screenshot]

If LibreOffice is the only thing with a messed up display, I would suspect that box to not be checked (and possibly another font specified on the Fonts window farther down the list).  If so, select that box to use the system font.  You might need to quit and restart LibreOffice for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for answering. With the option `Use system font for user interface` unchecked, it does not show me strange symbols. But it still displays those symbols in the options menu, but not in the submenus... weird :S

Comment: Click on the fonts window on the left side several options down.  Check whether any replacement fonts have been defined in the top half of the window (normally, that would be empty).  If the option to use system fonts is checked, and the system fonts display normally elsewhere, it ought to work in LibreOffice.  This is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

I've expected the same problem: strange fonts in LibreOffice (and Konsole). I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 & XFCE. The reason was one of the following:

1. In *settings manager* - *appearance* the default font was set (by me) as "dingbats"
2. Eventually, in *windows manager* the *title font*, was also set as "dingbats"

After changing both to another ("normal") font - LibreOffice (and Konsole) regained its normal appearance.